# python __getattr__ autocompletion

Tags: python, autocomplete, attributes, tab-completion

`__getattr__` can be used to define attributes of objects. E.g. the following code will return `'bar'`.

```
class Test(object):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key == 'foo':
            return 'bar'
t = Test()
t.foo
```

To make life a bit easier I would like be able to type `t.` in ipython and then tab-complete the attribute name. I don't seem to be able to find how this can be done, while it seems to be possible. E.g. run the following code in ipython

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'foo': ('bar',)})
```

Typing `df.` and tab-completing allows to select the `foo` option. I could not find how pandas does this in its code, so I'm asking here. What should I add to my `Test` class such that tab-completion will work?

Comment: I believe that it's not `pandas` doing it, but `ipython` adapting themselves to known classes. Maybe they've got an API for that, maybe they don't provide extensions.

Comment: If that's true ipython inspects `df` to find its columns, right? I was hoping for something along the lines of an `__attrs__` attribute that contains a list of valid attributes.

Comment: If that's the case then there might be an answer; but that might also be a specific scan for known classes, that is different and dependent on the class.

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this with `__dir__` method.
below is an example for a class that contains a DataFrame

```
def __dir__(self):
    return self.df.keys()
```

Comment: Thank's I had the same problem and it solved it ! This should be an accepted answer.